# Does Docker stack in Portainer support `Docker compose profiles`?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, portainer, docker-stack

I am using the next tools versions:

- Ubuntu version: 22.04.1
- Docker version: 23.0.0, build e92dd87
- Docker compose version: v2.16.0
- Portainer version: 2.17.0

I am trying to setup the stack from **Git repository** via Portainer by following [the next instruction from official docs](https://docs.portainer.io/user/docker/stacks/add#option-3-git-repository).

I am using 2 profiles: `dev` and `prod` so my docker `docker-compose.yml` file looks like below:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  backend:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myproject
    profiles: ["dev", "prod"]

  db:
    image: postgres:15.2-alpine3.17
    profiles: ["dev", "prod"]

  frontend:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myproject_frontend
    profiles: ["dev", "prod"]

volumes:
  db_data:
  frontend_data:
  logs:
```

When I tried to use my `prod` profile in Portainer stack via `COMPOSE_PROFILES` ENV variable as was proposed in [this Portainer issue](https://github.com/portainer/portainer/issues/5796) like `COMPOSE_PROFILES=prod docker compose up` then I get the same error if I don't use any ENV variable at all. The error says:

```
Deployment error
failed to deploy a stack: no service selected
```

I tried to specify the path to the `docker-compose.prod.yml` file in the `Additional paths` field, but got the same error as above. If I try to use the path to `docker-compose.prod.yml` in `Compose path` then I got the the next error for every named volume:

```
 service "frontend" refers to undefined volume "frontend_data"
```

I thought that something wrong in my `docker-compose.prod.yml` file, but when I copied its content to `docker-compose.yml` (and also deleted `COMPOSE_PROFILES` ENV variable) then Stack was successfully created.

So my question about ability to use **Docker compose profiles** in Portainer Stacks. Is it impossible or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abandoned Docker stack (wanted to use it in the first place to automatically update containers after GitHub repository changes) and used **GitHub's Container Registry** + **Watchtower** (containrrr/watchtower).

below my working code from `.github/workflows/publish.yml`, maybe it will be useful for someone

```
on:
  # any code pushed to master and develop branch will be a trigger
  push:
    branches: ["master", "develop"]

name: Deploy
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Build Compose Images
        run: docker compose -f docker-compose.publish.yml build

      # seems that `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN` and `github.actor` provided by Github automatically (https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#using-the-github_token-in-a-workflow)
      - name: Log into registry
        run: echo "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" | docker login ghcr.io -u ${{ github.actor }} --password-stdin

      - name: Push image to Container Registry
        run: docker compose -f docker-compose.publish.yml push
```

some side notes about `docker-compose.publish.yml`

- used `version: '3.8'` at the first line
- used directive code for `db` service with Postgres to avoid its publishing

```
    deploy:
      replicas: 0
```

- used next `image` directive for frontend and backend services, `container_name` directive is the same as `project_name` in image

```
image: ghcr.io/name_of_our_organization_on_github/project_name_backend # `:latest` version used by default
container_name: project_name_backend
...
image: ghcr.io/name_of_our_organization_on_github/project_name_frontend # `:latest` version used by default
container_name: project_name_frontend
```